# Does iOS app publisher also need Mac, or only developer needs it?

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I'm a contractor who develops apps for companies other than my own.
My client plans to distribute game with his legal entity name as the “Seller”, so he enrolled iOS Developer Program.

I own Mac connected with my developer account, and builds of our game signed with my provisioning profile and certificates (for Ad Hoc testing).

**Now we want to publish game using my client's account.**

**Should I tell him to buy Mac?** Or maybe I can use my Mac to build game with my certificates and provisioning profiles and then use his account to publish game signed by me?

I would highly appreciate any suggestion, I have not found any revelant documentation in Apple support. It would be great if my client wouldn't need to buy new machine just to sell game that is already developed.

Thanks in advance,

Kris

Comment: You can use your own mac and add another (your employer) developer account in the XCode/Preferences/Accounts and use it to distribute the app. Or he can add your private account to his team once he enrolled iOS Dev Program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your own mac and sign the app with your client's provisioning profiles and certificates (they have to make you a Developer profile in their Apple Dev team).
Then, the thing you need is your client's  Itunes Connect account to upload the app with the Application Loader.

Comment: Thanks, making me Developer of his Apple Dev team solved everything - with it I was able to generate certificates from my Mac. Without that I was unable to create certificate from his account because it requires XCode (so it does require Mac).

Answer (score 1):

No need to Purchase Mac for just publishing the apps,Firstly Create Distribution Profile & Certificate with your client's account.
Then Create a new app after login on itunesconnect with your app details & screenshots.Then Publish your app directly through **XCode** or with **Application Loader**.

Answer (score 0):

You only need MAC in order to have XCode and apple tools which you use them to create and sign applications with the appropriate provisioning profiles.

For the publisher, it is sufficient if you provide him with an ipa signed with enterprise distribution provisioning profile OR if you upload from your xcode to the itunes the signed application with distribution provisioning profile.

The publisher's only work is to prepare the upload on itunesconnect (meaning screenshots and stuff) .  All his work is done in a browser, so he can use Linux for all that matters .